# How to make print or the write function atomic in Lua?

Tags: lua

I used the following code to simultaneously write to a file or stdout using multiple cores:

```
f:write(x, "\t", y, "\n")
print(x, '\t', y, '\n')
```

How can I make those statements atomic without racing?

Update: it seems that my question caused confusion. Therefore I'll ask the more specific question: if I run the code above on different processors but pipe the output into the same file, how can I make sure that the output from different processors stay in different lines as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you concatenate your substrings together using `..` you increase the chances that the resulting string is handed to the OS in a single go.

```
f:write( x .. "\t" .. y .. "\n" )
f:flush()
io.write( tostring( x ) .. "\t" .. tostring( y ) .. "\n" )
io.flush()
```

This *may* be good enough for rather unimportant tasks like logging. If it is not good enough, you need to serialize the output operations. One possiblity for that is file locking. The popular [luafilesystem](http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/) module (portable to all major desktop OSes) includes `lock` and `unlock` functions for that purpose:

```
local lfs = require( "lfs" )

while not lfs.lock( f, "w" ) do end
f:write( x, "\t", y, "\n" )
f:flush()
lfs.unlock( f )
f:close()
```

Unfortunately you have to do a busy wait for the lock. If you are able to use the `fcntl` function in [luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix/) (only available for POSIX OSes like Linux or MacOS), you can make the calling process block until the lock can be acquired (see [here](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix/blob/master/examples/lock.lua) for an example, but use `F_SETLKW` instead of `F_SETLK`). (For the `print` case I would use locks on a temporary file somewhere -- I haven't found a Lua module that provides access to semaphores or equivalent yet.)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a reason that the double dot increases the chance of the resulting string being handed in a single go?

Comment: Yes. The `..` operator concatenates the parts together and creates a single string argument, which it passes to the output function, which in turn most likely passes it as a single argument to the underlying C function, and the underlying (atomic) system call. The original version passes multiple arguments to the output function and the underlying C function, which _could_ result in multiple system calls.

Answer (score 5):

Lua itself doesn't support real multi-threading. So there's no such problems as racing.

Note that this means in your code `f:write` and `print` aren't executed simultaneously, even in multi-core processors.

Comment: Maybe I was using "racing" incorrectly. I didn't use threading, instead, I ran the same program with different input parameters on different processors, and wrote the results into one single file. As a result, the output can be unexpected, for example, output from different processors aren't in different lines.